# Why does the Puerto Rico governor get to forcefully pass bills rejected by their house and senate votes via a executive order?

Tags: puerto-rico

I recently heard that the governor of Puerto Rico forced a bill to pass regarding charging for grocery bags, via an executive order, after the bill was voted down by both the house and the senate. Since this was a non emergency situation, how is this ever allowed?

Comment: Is there anything that would _disallow_ it?

Comment: Good question. If governors can just use executive orders to bypass due process. Wouldn’t nothing stop him from being a tyrant. Due process in modern day representive governance requires proposed bills to go through the process of approval before its ever placed before the governor to sign.

Comment: If [this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_Puerto_Rico#Governor) is anything to go by, the Governor can issue orders very much like POTUS can issue Executive Orders. Seeing how Trump can savage Obamacare without Congress or Senate, it seems weird to expect García Padilla to not be allowed to ban - of all things - plastic bags. :-)

Comment: Can you add a source for what it is that you heard?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - right, because Trump surely [invented partisan governing by executive order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_executive_actions_by_Barack_Obama#Executive_orders)

Comment: If it's true ("I heard" is not really a reliable source, you know :-)), the obvious answer is because the Puerto Ricans wrote their constitution to allow it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Puerto_Rico

Comment: @user4012: I honestly don't care what Obama or anyone before him did, and I've literally zero stakes in this - I was merely putting banning plastic bags in perspective.

Comment: @user17384 In many countries there's different kind of laws, in france and spain, There's Legislative Orders; legislative Laws, Legislative Ammendmends, Executive Orders, Executive Ammendmends... (to the infinite). Some complex measures can only be resolved via executive or even constitutional laws / reforms / ammendmends. For example, this plastic bag could be treated as a new Legislative Law ( parliament, senate) or a ammendment to the Consumer Code ( Executive ammendment).